# Warning from PhpStorm: Assigned expression type jQuery is not assignable to type string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phpstorm

```
$('a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== '_blank') {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    }
});
```

The code above show a warning message in PhpStorm:

> Assigned expression type jQuery is not assignable to type string

How can I fix it?

Comment: I tried your code verbatim and it seems to work fine.  Are you sure this snippet is causing the warning?

Comment: Also, is this supposed to make links with `id="_blank"` do nothing?  In that case don't forget to add `e.preventDefault()`, where `e` is the event parameter in the callback function.

Comment: Wait, are you using TypeScript?

Comment: I code this in phpstorm, the warning info is not show in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

This code works perfect with Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <script>
        (function(){
            $('a').click(function () {
             if ($(this).attr('id') !== '_blank') {
               window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
             }
            });
        })();

</script>
```

Hope it helps